# Writing to File Share in Batch File on Azure VM does not work if called from outside VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-files

I have a batch script on an Azure Windows VM.

This script contains a part, where a file will be saved on an Azure File Share Storage (Z:/). This is working if I call the batch script inside the VM.

But if I call the Batch Script from outside (e.g. via RunCommand) then I get the error "the system cannot find the path specified".

My first try to fix it was to check the assigments but I could not solve the issue. Do I have to mount the drive first if I call the script outside or what could be the solution?

Comment: RunCommand Scripts run as the System User. The share mapping(Z:) is not created for System so it can not access it. Try accessing it as UNC Path with credentials...

Answer (score 0):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to Map the Azure Fileshare in Azure VM from a remote machine:**

```
#Connect AzAccount with Elevated Credentials
Connect-AzAccount

# Get the VM List
Get-AzVM
```

[image]

Save the below PowerShell script in your local drive to mount the **Azure Fileshare** in **Azure VM**.

```
$connectTestResult = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName emobro.file.core.windows.net -Port 445
if ($connectTestResult.TcpTestSucceeded) {
    
    cmd.exe /C "cmdkey /add:`"emobro.file.core.windows.net`" /user:`"localhost\emobro`" /pass:`"3UVLFs/135fb8mkXfKrj349PZJ9yJyZZWuSAQeXPFgp8htuuHDPW7HziFCUDzQ8yUEJ9pknND1l1+ASteMrMhg==`""
 
    New-PSDrive -Name J -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\emobro.file.core.windows.net\emo" -Persist
} else {
    Write-Error -Message "Unable to reach the Azure storage account via port 445. Check to make sure your organization or ISP is not blocking port 445, or use Azure P2S VPN, Azure S2S VPN, or Express Route to tunnel SMB traffic over a different port."
}
```

Add above powershell script path on below script.

```
$script = "C:\xxxxx\Venkat\Poweshell\Fileshare.ps1" 

Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName Mindtree_ResourceGroup -Name windowsVm  -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath 'C:\Venkat\Venkat\Poweshell\Fileshare.ps1'
```

Once ran the above command **Fileshare** is mounted successfully on **Azure VM** from remote machine.

[image]

[image]

You can use the below approach also to mount **Azure Fileshare** using **Runcommand** from **Azure Portal**.

**Open your VM> Run command > RunPowerShellScript**

[image]

Refer: [Run PowerShell Scripts for Azure VMs using Azure Automation](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2022/08/schedule-and-run-powershell-scripts-for-azure-vms-using-azure-automation/) created by `Thomas Maurer`